# numbers 1 to 21 on circle with sum at least 33

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

if we write `1,2,3,....,21` on a circle. there are at least one three consecutive set with sum at least 33.

obviously the main idea is strictly increasing on sum of numbers. but i wanna know how to organize the solution.

Comment: What have you tried? Where have your approaches gotten stuck? Also, "combinatorics way" is a bit vague. Could you be more specific?

Comment: l know that i should solve with The original pigeonhole. but can not write it in true way.

Comment: How many "three consecutive sets" are there? What is the *total* of their sum?

Comment: @AMZ What do you mean by "consecutive sets"? Can you write an example?

Comment: @MohammadAliNematollahi I am guessing that the numbers "1" through "21" are randomly positioned around the table.  Then, you can choose any arbitrary position at the table and label it $x_1$.  Then, you can assume that the positions going clockwise around the table are assigned the labels $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_{21}$.  Under this assumption, I interpret the query to intend that the consecutive sets of 3 are represented by the 21 sets $\{x_1, x_2, x_3\}, \{x_2, x_3, x_4\}, \{x_3, x_4, x_5\}, \cdots, \{x_{19}, x_{20}, x_{21}\}, \{x_{20}, x_{21}, x_1\}, \{x_{21}, x_1, x_2\}.$

Comment: **Assuming so**, I think that player3236's comment hits the nail on the head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $21$ consecutive $3$ sets. Each number appears $3$ times in these $21$ sets. Moreover, the sum of numbers $1$ to $21$ is $ \dfrac{21 \times 22}{2} = 11 \times 21 $. So the sum of numbers of these sets will be:
$$ 3 \times \dfrac{21 \times 22}{2} = 33 \times 21. $$
Now, if all these sets have sum less than $33$, then the sum of numbers of these $21$ sets will be less than $33 \times 21$, a contradiction.